# Smooth scrolling brush with scaleband like string labels

Tags: d3.js, zooming, smooth-scrolling, pan

The problem: Using scaleband does not pan smoothly using brush.

https://shanegibney.github.io/D3-v4-Bar-chart-Scaleband-with-Brush/

Here is an example of smooth panning with dates on x-axis.

https://shanegibney.github.io/d3-Bar-Chart-Pan-And-Zoom/

But this only works when the x-domain is continuous.

Using a linearscale, I would like to replace the values on the x-axis with the string in data d.name. The issue is that when zooming new ticks are created in between the value. For example the values 1 and 2 when zoomed will produce values and tciks for 1,  1.5,  2 and 2.5 etc. This means that the names do not match up anymore.

This could be solved with two things;

1. Prevent new ticks appearing when zooming in. I don't know how to do this.
2. Replace each label on the x-axis ticks with d.name from the data

These are my attempts to do this,

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
      label = data[i].name;
      local.set(this, data[i].name);
      return "test";
      return data[i].name;
      return label;
      return i;
      return d;
    });
```

None of which work.

The Plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/zbWu6AV8MNO9N8m0byre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `tickFormat` function, check if the numeric tick corresponds to any value in the `data` array. If it does, return the `name`, otherwise return nothing:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
        var found = data.find(function(e){
            return e.num === d
        });
        return found ? found.name : null; 
    })
```

Here is the code with that change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: avenir next, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .zoom {
    cursor: move;
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .axis {
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    stroke: #888;
    font: 10px avenir next, sans-serif;
  }

  .axis>path {
    stroke: #888;
  }

</style>

<body>
  <div id="totalDistance">
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  /* Adapted from: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172 */
  var data = [{
      "name": "A",
      "date": "2016-11-09 11:15",
      "num": "1",
      "distance": "1900"
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "date": "2016-11-10 10:40",
      "num": "2",
      "distance": "1500"
    },
    {
      "name": "C",
      "date": "2016-11-11 16:45",
      "num": "3",
      "distance": "2500"
    },
    {
      "name": "D",
      "date": "2016-11-12 12:48",
      "num": "4",
      "distance": "2300"
    },
    {
      "name": "E",
      "date": "2016-11-15 20:00",
      "num": "5",
      "distance": "2000"
    }
  ];

  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 90,
      left: 50
    },
    margin2 = {
      top: 230,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 300 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");

  var local = d3.local();

  var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);
  // dur = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 12]);

  var tickLabels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

  var newData = [];
  data.forEach(function(e) {
    newData.push({
      "name": e.name
    });
  });

  //var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0);
  var xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2).tickSize(0)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      var found = data.find(function(e) {
        return e.num === d
      });
      return found ? found.name : null;
    })
  yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      var found = data.find(function(e) {
        return e.num === d
      });
      if (!found) {
        d3.select(this.parentNode).select("line").remove()
      }
      return found ? found.name : null;
    })

  // var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  //   .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
  //     label = data[i].name;
  //     local.set(this, data[i].name);
  //     return "test";
  //     return data[i].name;
  //     return label;
  //     return i;
  //     return d;
  //   });

  var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height2]
    ])
    .on("start brush end", brushed);

  var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .translateExtent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

  // d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  // if (error) throw error;

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");
  var mouseoverTime = d3.timeFormat("%a %e %b %Y %H:%M");
  var minTime = d3.timeFormat("%b%e, %Y");
  var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%b %Y");

  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.distance = +d.distance;
      d.num = +d.num;
      return d;
    },
    function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;
    });

  var total = 0;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    total = d.distance + total;
  });

  var minDate = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.num;
  });

  var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.num;
  });

  var yMax = Math.max(20, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.distance;
  }));

  x.domain([xMin, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.num;
  })]);
  y.domain([0, yMax]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  var rects = focus.append("g");
  rects.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
  rects.selectAll("rects")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return "#8DA5ED";
    })
    .attr("class", "rects")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.num);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.distance);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return 10;
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.distance);
    });

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);

  // Summary Stats
  focus.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
    .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Distance in meters");

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + ((width + margin.right + margin.left) / 2) + " ," +
      (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Date");

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

  var rects = context.append("g");
  rects.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
  rects.selectAll("rects")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return "#8DA5ED";
    })
    .attr("class", "rects")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x2(d.num);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y2(d.distance);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return 10;
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height2 - y2(d.distance);
    });

  context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, x.range());

  // });

  function brushed() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
    var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
    x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
    focus.selectAll(".rects")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.num);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.distance);
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return 10;
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.distance);
      });

    focus.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
    var e = d3.event.selection;
    var selectedrects = focus.selectAll('.rects').filter(function() {
      var xValue = this.getAttribute('x');
      return e[0] <= xValue && xValue <= e[1];
    });
  }

  function zoomed() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
    var t = d3.event.transform;
    x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
    focus.selectAll(".rects")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.num);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.distance);
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return 10;
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.distance);
      });

    focus.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
    context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
  }

</script>
```

---

PS: this is clearly a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): disguising a linear scale as an categorical scale, as you're doing here, may not be the correct solution. Instead of that, you should find out how to brush the band scale itself.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to smoothly brush/pan when using the scaleband()? I thought scaleband always equally separated bars and never positions them anywhere else, so that smooth panning would be impossible. Thanks

Comment: If I could just prevent the extra ticks appearing, I'd be very happy with the behaviour as in your snippet. Thanks a lot for it.

Comment: I will post another question asking how to prevent extra ticks when using brush and zoom. Thanks

Comment: No need for another question, check the snippet again.

Comment: Oh wow! How did you do that? I genuinely can't see where you did that.

Comment: This part: `if (!found) { d3.select(this.parentNode).select("line").remove()}`.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you